# jQuery: changing css of an event target

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Here's a fiddle where I can't get it to work http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/rAPcQ/22/

I have html where user clicks a button to add a friend's name

```
 <button id="add-friend">Add Friend</button>

<ul id="friends-list"> </ul>
```

Beside each name on the list, there's a span element rich? the user can click to indicate if the person is rich

```
Jim     [rich?]
```

I want the color of the name to change if the user clicks the span. I also want the html of the span (i.e. rich?) to change, so that the user can toggle back and forth

In my view, I created an event like this

```
events: {
      'click span.swap':  'swap',

    },
```

so that when the user clicks the span, a 'swap' function is called.

```
swap: function(e) {

    var spin = e.target;
    var tit =  $(spin).css('color');

    if (tit === 'blue') {

        $(spin).css('color', 'black');
        $(spin).html('poor?');

    } else {

        $(spin).css('color', 'blue');
        $(spin).html('rich?');

    }
```

The code in the "swap" function changes the css and html of the element that was clicked. It will change

Jim     [rich?] //originally blue

to

Jim     [poor?] //'poor' is now black

and then give you the ability to toggle if it's already been switched once. However, the code inside 'swap' function is not working, (even though it's passing jsLint).

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

Bonus points if you can tell me how to change the css of the person's name, which is wrapped in a class "friend" in the same function.

```
<span class="friend" style="color:pink">' + this.model.get('name') + '</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="swap" style="font-family:sans-serif; color:blue; cursor:pointer;">[rich?]</span>
```

HTML

```
 <button id="add-friend">Add Friend</button>

<ul id="friends-list"> </ul>
```

This is the container for the list elements, which are added then added individually through a backbone.js view

Comment: Please show the html, what's the structure of the `li` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UJ4HN/  (updated)

swap function

```
swap: function(e) {

    var $spin = this.$('.swap');
    var $name = this.$('.friend');
    var text =  $spin.text();


    if (text.indexOf('rich') != -1) {

        $spin.css('color', 'black');
        $name.css('color', 'green');   //here color for name
        $spin.html('[poor?]');

    } else  {

        $spin.css('color', 'blue');
        $name.css('color', 'red');     //here color for name
        $spin.html('[rich?]');

    }
 },
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this issue because computed style is converted to rgb color.

blue becomes rgb(0, 0, 255) and your conditional statement doesn't match.

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute. Zombies up at 2:52am... ;-) For the bonus though, if you just want to change the CSS you can include this in the swap function on each side of the conditional `this.$('.friend').css('color','black');` or blue. Further note, it might be a good idea to use `this.$(//element)` to do your DOM selection. This limits searching for the element to elements WITHIN the view.el. Equivalent to `view.$el.find(//element)`

Comment: Changed it to RGB but can't get it to work. Am I doing it right? http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/rAPcQ/29/